# How to access sessionStorage in middleware Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next.js13

I am currently coding an authentication system in my next js app that is using app router. My app has a login and user dashboard route. When user logged in successfully(with the correct username and password).I save the user data in session storage. So when a user tries to go to the dashboard page, I want to check if user is logged in or not(data existence in session storage) . I think I can do it in the dashboard component file too but because there are more routes like dashboard which need to be protected , I think it is better to check it in middleware . So how can I access session storage in middleware to check user is logged in or not . Allow user to access route or not . I tried to access session storage to check user authentication status but I got an error which says sessionStorage is not defined . I think it is because middleware process is in server-side and session storage is in client side. So how can I do this ? Any idea ?

Comment: if you tell a little bit about how you set the authentication in your app

Comment: you should explain this in the question.

Comment: I added more details to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is to use the cookies using [cookies-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next). cookies are attached on every request automatically

If you insist on using `sessionStorage`, nextjs13 app directory has `RootLayout` file. you can either check here if the user authenticated or you can create a context provider for authentication and check the authentication inside `useEffect`. if user is not authenticated, you can redirect the user to `login` page.

Comment: Yeah , I exactly did it before . As I said I can check it inside dashboard component too but is there any way to do this in middleware file ?

Comment: you should set cookie. cookies will be automatically attached to the request object and you could extract the cookie in middleware